# Any way to convert Java constants in a Constants class to an iterative form in another?

Tags: java, arrays, constants, iteration

I have a constants class full of a bunch of final static strings.  I need a way to get access to all these constants in this class in a nice array type form without manually created an array with each constant.

Is there any type of method on a class that could give me back an iterative data-structure that I could loop through in another class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the declared fields:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class field1 {
    private double d;
    public static final int i = 37;
    String s = "testing";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        field1 f = new field1();

        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("field1");

            Field fieldlist[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fieldlist) {
                System.out.println("name = " + field.getName());
                System.out.println("decl class = " + field.getDeclaringClass());
                System.out.println("type = " + field.getType());

                int mod = field.getModifiers();
                System.out.println("modifiers = " + Modifier.toString(mod));
                System.out.println("value = " + field.get(f));
                System.out.println("-----");
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This sample is from [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: +1 - reflection is the only way to avoid having to create an array.

Comment: If I wanted to get the value of that constant instead of the constant name - How would I go about doing that from this code?

Comment: I have extended the example above. It now prints the value too.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using an `enum`

```
enum Foo{
    //do stuff
}
```

Then you can *iterate* through the constants using [`Foo.values()`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9), as such

```
for(Foo f: Foo.values()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Reference: [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is `Class.getFields()`. However, defining your own array would be simpler and give you control over the contents and order.

Depending on your needs, you might be able to create a single array, once.

```
public static final String FOO = "foo";
public static final String BAR = "bar";
public static final String BAZ = "baz";
public static final String[] ALL = { FOO, BAR, BAZ };
```

Alternatively, you could replace all the String constants with enumerators, and provide a toString() method in the enumeration. How much work this is depends on your existing codebase.